# External AV microphone connection ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, microphone, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to interface microphone with my embedded board which has ubuntu 18.04 image in it. My microphone is connected to the x86 board using AV connection. So, how does this AV type of connection(RCA) shows up in ubuntu? I mean if we are using USB related devices ,they show up in /dev right? so, how does this type of connection show up as? I tried to see it in /dev/snd/by-path and /proc/asound/cards/ etc..is this the way? Ultimately I want to use this for gstreamer input to do some speech recognition stuff.Please help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find answer using the following link

https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc

Although I did not have asoundrc file in my home directory,I was able to determine which hardware device that I am accessing using arecord --list-devices and I was able to construct a gstreamer pipeline using alsasrc

gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc device="hw:1" ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux  !  filesink location=test105.mp3

Thank you! further info on this is much appreciated too! Always curious to learn more!